# simple function for filter words on page

Tags: javascript, function

I write function for search title of state, and everything works perfect but when i type letters in search bar filter look for all letters in word. I want make filter search from beginning word.

example

if i type an filter result will be c'an'ada he find an and that its ok but i want to check only from beginning

```
function filterNames() {
    let filterValue = document.getElementById('filterInput').value.toUpperCase();
    let kartice = allContinet;
    let h2 = document.querySelectorAll('h2');

    for (let i=0;i<h2.length;i++) {
        let name = h2[i].getElementsByClassName("ime-zemlje");

        if (name[0].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
            kartice[i].style.display = '';
        } else {
            kartice[i].style.display = 'none';
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.search` method of `String`.

So your `if` condition will become

```
if(name[0].innerHTML.toUpperCase().search(new RegExp(`^${filterVal}`)) === 0)
```

`search` has good browser support as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) instead of `indexOf`

```
if (name[0].innerHTML.toUpperCase().startsWith(filterValue)) { }
```

This is a [ES2015+ feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Specifications). If it is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Browser_compatibility) in your browser, you can add [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill)

Or you can use regex with a `^` and [`i` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) to match only those strings which start with `filterValue` irrespetive of case:

```
var regex = new RegExp('^' + filterValue, 'i')
if(regex.test(name[0].innerHTML)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function filterNames() {
    var filterValue = document.getElementById('filterInput').value;
    
    //console.log(filterValue);
    var h2 = document.querySelectorAll('h2.ime-zemlje');//for h2+sime-zemlje class
    for (var i=0;i<h2.length;i++) {
        //console.log(h2[i].innerText);
        if(filterValue.length<1){
          h2[i].innerHTML=h2[i].innerText;
          continue;
        }
        var GD=h2[i].innerText;
        var QQ="";
        var pos = 0;
        while (pos != -1) {
          pos = GD.indexOf(filterValue, 0);
          //console.log(pos);
          if(pos!=-1){
            QQ+=GD.substring(0, pos);//Add Back Normal Word
            QQ+='<span style="color: red;">'+GD.substring(pos, pos+filterValue.length)+'</span>';//Add Back Search Word And Be Colorful
            GD=GD.substring(pos+filterValue.length, GD.length);//Remove Add Back Word Then Next Loop Not Search Again
          }
        }
        h2[i].innerHTML=QQ+GD;
        
        
        
        
        //console.log(QQ+GD);

    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="filterInput" onchange="filterNames()"></input>
<h2 class="ime-zemlje">I Love Little Girl</h2>
<h2 class="ime-zemlje">I Love Loli</h2>
<h2 class="QQQQQQ">I Scared FBI</h2>
```

Key In Love Or I you will See what you want